# Do --limit-xxx options of service command limit resource per service or per container?

Tags: docker

`service create` command of docker 1.12 has two options to limit cpu and memory as follows:

> ```
>   --limit-cpu value              Limit CPUs (default 0.000)
>   --limit-memory value           Limit Memory (default 0 B)
> ```

Do they limit resource per service or per container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see in [api/client/service/update.go](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/e2a26744f987199dca7eacf93e3e236764c87f5e/api/client/service/update.go#L132-L135)

```
taskResources().Limits = &swarm.Resources{}
updateInt64Value(flagLimitCPU, &task.Resources.Limits.NanoCPUs)
```

`--limit-cpu` was introduced in [commit 12a00e6](https://github.com/docker/docker/commit/12a00e60177ca42bfb1dd9ebd5dce1c7039da6dd)

Considering that [swarmkit/manager/scheduler/nodeinfo.go](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/0ef720ededc24018ce1f727814b1a9ae93897891/vendor/src/github.com/docker/swarmkit/manager/scheduler/nodeinfo.go#L36) has, when removing a task, the following code:

```
nodeInfo.AvailableResources.NanoCPUs += reservations.NanoCPUs
```

It appears limit-cpu is per node managed by a service.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried some experiments and I agree with you.

Comment: @npcode thank you for this confirmation. It could be clearer in the doc ;)