# Docker - cpu limit configuration

Tags: docker

I would like to set limitation of cpu resource, and found this docker-compose setting file below.

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.001'
          memory: 50M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.0001'
          memory: 20M
```

BUT I don't know what 0.001 mean in here. It will use 0.1% of total cpu capacity? and some document said it can be set more than 1. what happen If i set more than 1?

and What is default value of resource.limits.cpus and resource.limits.cpus.memory?

Comment: These values are absurdly small :/

Answer (score 1):

By default a container has limitless access to the host's cpu. Limits allow you to configure resources that are available to a container.

A cpus value of 0.001 will mean for each one second, a 1 millisecond will be available to the container.

A value greater than 1 will make sense when you think of hosts with multi-cpus. A value of 2 for instance will mean the container will be given access for at most 2 cpus.

Answer (score 1):

The *limits* are the maximum docker will use for the container. The *reservations* are how much it will set aside for the container i.e. prevent other containers from using.

CPU is measured in percentage of a second on a single CPU. So the example you have will limit you to 0.1% of a CPU (1ms/s), which might be useful for some I/O bound tasks.  '1.0' would allow one CPU to be used entirely, and higher values would allow multiple CPUs to be allocated (or reserved) to the container.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38949901/4822566) has some graphs showing the effects.